# Use extension function from different context in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Here is an example of what I'd like to achieve:

```kotlin
open class A {
   open fun Int.foo() {
      print("foo")
   }
}

object B: A() {
   val number = 5;

   override fun Int.foo() {
      print("overriden foo");
      
      // I want to call the A.(Int.foo())
   }
}

B.number.foo(); //outputs: "foooverriden foo"
```

First of all, does anything like this exist? Can I somehow assume `number` to be in the context of `class A` in its override method? How would I write this?

The more I think about it the more it twists my mind. Of course, you cannot call `number.super.foo()` because super for `number` is `kotlin.Number`. You cannot cast it to `A` because Int has nothing to do with A. The only way I can think about solving this to somehow import the extension function itself and rename it with `as`, but I cannot do that here since it is inside a class, so I cannot just import it. Any suggestions?

My use case for this is that I have a class where I manipulate some data, then in special cases, I want to manipulate it differently, but fall back to the original code as the last option. I could use normal functions instead of extension functions of course, but in my case, it comes natural to use extension functions, so I wanted to see if this could be achieved somehow.

Comment: how would you do this with normal functions? Assuming you have a function that receives an int in `B` and `A`, how would you specify which one to invoke from `B`? Asking because I cannot see how this would be possible. This is why it's called overriding as far as I can tell.

Comment: when this is a normal function in `B` foo I would call `super.foo()`. There the `this` is `B` and super is `A`

Comment: Ah I misunderstood. I thought you meant to call it from the outside. However, `this` is not `B`, `this` is actually `Int` inside the extension function. Maybe this is why it's confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is impossible so far, I'm afraid.

There's an open issue for this on JetBrains' issue-tracking system: [KT-11488](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-11488).  There's a Kotlin work-around there, though that needs tweaks to the class designs.

(Also discussed on the JetBrains [discussion board](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/when-overriding-a-member-extension-function-how-to-call-superclass-implementation/1529).  That mentions another workaround requiring a Java class.)

Answer (score 0):

```
override fun Int.foo() {
   print("overriden foo")
   
   with (A()) {
      foo()
   }
}
```

Of course this is a bit of a hack and will get worse if `A` has some state which `foo()` depends on, which you'll then need to set manually.